# How do you handle mouse control in a Perl web application?

Tags: perl, mouse

I intend to develop web chess application with Perl.

And, wonder which method is most suitable to use mouse tracking without installing many sequenced GUI modules at web side?

I have noticed that i need a simple and fast module to valuate mouse coordinates that already can moves objects at web page. Also mouse click button actions has to be considered.

Answer should include faster, compact, most easy and suitable. LET us inform we beginners preferred mouse usage script and module of yours.

Answer (score 9):

If you want responsive mouse actions (as I assume you do for drag-dropping pieces), then you need to do it on the client side. That rules out doing it in Perl (or any other server side language); your options are basically limited to JavaScript, a Flash object or a Java applet.

Comment: Yes, your reply is subject for another solution.

Comment: You *could* do it [client side in Perl](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/Components/Windows/PerlScript.html#client_side), but the number of people running a browser with the right plugins to support it is very close to zero.

Comment: @Quentin - OUCH. I'm not sure whether to whoop with joy or cringe at the sheer lunacy of this :)

Comment: @DVK — it made a lot more sense when it was introduced, I think I was writing stuff for IE 3 or 4 when I found out about it. Back then JS wasn't the clear winner in client side scripting land.